# How to remove duplicated columns with the same value regardless of the column names in R?

Tags: r

Input:

```
a<- c(1,2,2)
b<- c(1,2,2)
c<- c(1,2,3)
d<- c(0,0,0)
e<- c(0,0,0)

f<- cbind(a,b,c,d,e)
```

What I want (look at the outcome):

```
whatIwant<- cbind(a,c,d)
```

- I do not want to remove the columns by column names because it's a huge dataframe
- I am not concerned about the column names
  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`duplicated` gives you duplicates row-wise, here you want to find duplicates column wise. So take transpose of the matrix that you have, find out the duplicates and use it to subset columns.

```
result <- f[, !duplicated(t(f))]
result

#     a c d
#[1,] 1 1 0
#[2,] 2 2 0
#[3,] 2 3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unique(f,MARGIN=2)

     a c d
[1,] 1 1 0
[2,] 2 2 0
[3,] 2 3 0
```